# Construct take function as boolean? Zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In ZF2

```
class UsuarioController extends AbstractActionController{

    public function __construct(){        
          $this->valido();          
    } 

    public function valido(){
        $headCookie = $this->getRequest()->getHeaders()->get('Cookie');
        if(array_key_exists('c_user', get_object_vars($headCookie))){
            $c_user = $headCookie->c_user;
                if($c_user== 0 || null){
                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
                }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

Warning: get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given in /var/www/html/ZendSkeletonApplication/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/UsuarioController.php on line 42

Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/html/ZendSkeletonApplication/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/UsuarioController.php on line 42

Answer (score 1):

Method `get()` from `Zend\Http\Headers` (http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.3/classes/Zend.Http.Headers.html#get) returns boolean if particular header is missing. This leads to error from get_object_vars and then from array_key_exists.

Use default parameter (second argument for `get()`) or check if header is present before executing code that operates on it.